# Handling long running processes in Spring MVC controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Using Spring MVC, I have a controller that makes an API request to an external service that may take a long time. I am doing this synchronously because I want to return the external request result to the user. Ideally, this doesn't block an entire thread during this time, sort of like an async/await C# style idiom, but I'm not sure how to do that easily with Spring (or something else).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@Async](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html) annotation on some service method for asynchronous execution.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, AFAIK this will spin out an asynchronous task on a thread pool, and the only way to return the result to the client request is to cal get() on the Future which will block the request thread

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC is built on top of a Servlet, this means that (by default) anything you do inside a Controller method will block the request thread provided by Tomcat (Tomcat is the default servlet container for Spring Boot these days). 
If you are calling another HTTP based service, or Query a database inside your controller, you are probably making a blocking IO call. Blocking calls will always block the calling thread, the async/await in C# is just syntactical sugar, like Springs @Async it uses a hidden ThreadPool to do the actual work.

Unless you are able to call the upstream service using a NIO selector, you will need a thread to wait for the response, and in that case it makes most sense to just block on the Tomcat request thread, I believe the default number of request threads is 150, but you can set it higher if needed. If the upstream service can be called in a NIO manner, you only need one thread for all calls to that service, and you can can return a `DeferedResult` from your controller, and write the response to the client once the response from the upstream service has been produced.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Do not call the long running api from your main controller method. Just return the view (JSP).  Then you can fire an ajax request from your `document.ready` method in your view (Javascript). You can have a seperate `@ResourceRequest` annotated method in your controller to handle the ajax call.  Return the api result (as JSON or something) to the ajax caller. Once the view receives the ajax response, update the UI as you want.